# WMF image are not displaying in mozila firefox and google chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an image with .wmf extension  and i have to show it on the webpage

code is :

```
<img src="/coursePagePics/d75726573cf543948875fbf79ad46a39.wmf" height="100%"/>
```

It is working fine in IE8 but not in mozilla and chrome.

please help

Thanks

Comment: I am not aware that any browser except IE can display WMF files. You'll need to convert it, I believe.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew it worked after converting to jpg